# What ist a recommended way to do arithmetic with for loop indices when using size_type in C++?

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion, unsigned, size-type

I had a strange error in my program and it came down to a (for me) unexpected behaviour when doing a substraction between an int and a vector::size_type. Here is a simple example:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>

    typedef std::vector<double> state_type;

    int n = 1;

    int main() {

       state_type::size_type i = 0;
       std::cout << i - n << std::endl;

    }
```

I expected this program to prints -1, but it prints (compiled with icc 14.0.1 under 64bit Linux) :

```
    18446744073709551615
```

My current explanation is that size_type is unsigned and this leads to some weird (?) conversion ?
I only found this error after a long time and I am very surprised this happens. Now my question is how can I avoid these kind of mistakes, lets say in some for loop iterating over a std::vector:

```
   int n = 2;
   for(state_type::size_type i = 0; i < my_vec.size(); ++i) {
        if(i - n >= 0)
            my_vec[i - n] += 3;
   }
```

Of course I could take i as an int, but isn't it recommended to use size_type for these kind of loops ? What is a better way to do it ? Or am I the only one who is surprised by this conversion ?

Comment: You can avoid the issue entirely with std::vector by using an iterator

Comment: Why is `n` declared as an `int`? Why not just declare it as `size_type` and then check if `i >= n`?

Comment: It is _not_ recommended to use `size_type` for these kind of loops.  The index is an arithmetic value; as such, you want to avoid using an unsigned type for it.  (Also, if you use a signed type, you want to avoid comparisons for inequality with an unsigned type.  The end condition should be `i != my_vec.size()`; alternatively, you can cast the return value of `my_vec.size()` to an appropriate signed integral type.

Comment: I've never understood that argument. The index used for `std::vector::operator[]` is `size_type`, and it's unsigned. The main problem that I see is mixed-mode arithmetic. Using unsigned exclusively works well enough, at least if you don't make silly mistakes such as assuming `i>n` is equivalent to `i-n > 0`. That's problematic with any finite-range domain, including `int`. Consider `INT_MAX > INT_MIN`.

Answer (score 3):

This is a design flaw in the C++ standard library.  The unsigned
types in C++ are a bit special, and should not be used for
arithmetic quantities.  The way signed and unsigned mix is even
more special, and should be avoided even more.  The solution is
to not use `size_t` or the `size_type` typedefs, and in all but
extremely limited cases, to explicitly cast the return values of
`container::size()`, etc. to a signed integral type.  (In most
applications, `int` is safe; when in doubt, `ptrdiff_t` can be
used to avoid overflow.)

Comment: This answer seems useful, but is `This is a design flaw` an admitted issue, or personal opinion?

Comment: @zenzelezz I think it is an personal opinion!

Comment: @DieterLücking I think the C++ "giants" also pretty much agree that it's a flaw. It was discussed at GoingNative (I think). I think they agreed that unsigned types should only really be used for bitwise operations.

Comment: @Simple To be honest, it depends on who you consider "giants".  Those who generally argue for good software engineering principles do consider it a design flaw (or maybe a compromise necessary for conditions that are no longer relevant).  But there are so many people writing so many different things...  (The fact remains that using unsigned types for arithmetic quantities does lead to surprising results.  At least with the rules for unsigned and mixed mode arithmetic that C++ inherited from C.)

Answer (score 2):

Indeed in [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) the type `size_type` is documented as "an unsigned integral type" [...] "usually the same as [std::size_t](http://www.cplusplus.com/size_t)" (on my Debian/Sid/x86-64 it is a 64 bits unsigned integer). Probably passing `-Wall` to `g++` would have warned you.

So you better cast explicitly (perhaps to `std::ptrdiff_t`), e.g. use

```
int n = 2;
for(state_type::size_type i = 0; i < my_vec.size(); ++i) {
     if((std::ptrdiff_t) i - (std::ptrdiff_t) n >= 0)
         my_vec[i - n] += 3;
}
```

But in [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11) (with a recent compiler such as GCC 4.8.2) I would instead code perhaps:

```
   for (auto it= my_vec.begin(); it!=my_vec.end(); it++) {
     if (it > my_vec.begin()+n)
       *it += 3;
   }
```

Comment: `ssize_t` isn't in namespace `std`. You could use `std::ptrdiff_t` instead.

Comment: Even pre-C++11, you can use iterators.  Iterators only become problematic when you're iterating through several containers in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Standard C++ defines certain implicit conversion rules. 
signed integer type is converted to unsigned integer type if used together in an arithmetic expression, so when you subtraction, an arithmetic downflow occurs, resulting in (uint64_t)-1

size_type is documented as unsigned int. you can use size_t instead of int, and it's better to use iterator to iterate over a container.